# Remotely push PFX Cert and Private Key with .NET and Powershell

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, x509certificate2

The task at hand is to push a certificate from a central server to recipient servers.  I'm able to leverage the x509certificate2 methods to accomplish the certificate install.  Even tho the storage flags direct the add() method to install the private key, it doesn't install it on the remote machine.  In the code below, please trust that `$CertObj` is a x509certificate2 object created with the storage flags `Exportable`, `MachineKeySet`, and `PersistKeySet`.

```
Function Import-CertificateObject
{
    Param
    (
        [parameter(mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]
        $Computer
    )

    $CertStore = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store -ArgumentList "\\$($Computer)\$Location",$Store
    $CertStore.Open("ReadWrite")
    $CertStore.Add($CertObj)
    $CertStore.Close()

}
```

Using powershell to isolate the installed certificate object I can see that the `HasPrivateKey` property has been set to true.  This is the case when the installed certificate is inspected locally on the server and from the remote server which installed it.  Next, if you inspect the `PrivateKey` property from server which had the certificate installed, it's blank.  However, when inspected from the server which installed it, powershell returns object data for the private key.

Using ProcMon I could see that when the certificate is installing the regkey's for the private key it's doing so on the server which is performing the install on the remote server.  I need .Net to install the certificate private key on the remote machine.  I've read over the [x509certificate2 docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2(v=vs.110).aspx) but it doesn't touch on remote installs at all, nor is there an *in depth* explanation as to what these methods do.

I'm hoping it's as simple as changing an environment variable before the `add()` method, or maybe I've just totally approached this from the wrong angle.  So how do I get it to install the private key on the remote server, not the server pushing the cert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here was to leverage `Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock{}` to execute the code on the machine locally.

Answer (score 1):

You can't move/copy certificates with associated private keys over a network. With your code, you are just copying the public part of the certificate. Private key remains on a source server and is not moved/copied anywhere.

`HasPrivateKey` property is a store-attached property and has a little relation to the fact of existence of the private key and is not a reliable way to determine whether the private key is installed for that certificate.

The only correct way to copy certificate with private key across machines is to:

1. Export certificate and assiciated private key by using this: [Export(X509ContentType, SecureString)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148397.aspx) or this: [Export(X509ContentType, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24ww6yzk.aspx) overload.
2. copy PFX file to destination servers and use one of [these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.import.aspx) overloads to import certificate with private key to `X509Certificate2` object and use `X509Store` object to install it to the store.

However, be aware, that if private key was not marked as exportable during key generation or installation, your task will be impossible, because private key is protected by a CSP/KSP and you will be unable to export the key from provider.